# How to share MS Access front-end on Sharepoint - back-end on network drive

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I have a MS Access Database (2016) that I need to share with multiple users in several locations. Right now I have split the database and placed the back-end on a shared network drive. I have the front-end uploaded onto a folder in SharePoint (365).

I have never worked with SharePoint before, so any explanation will need to be fairly simple for me to follow.

I want users to be able to download a copy of the front-end so they can add data (through forms) and run reports/exports to Excel. I think that this is working now, without problems.

What I want to know is for myself, when I want to create a new query, form, or report, I want to save my changes to the front-end on SharePoint, not just to the copy that I download from SharePoint. How do I do this?

There is an existing database that someone else created (they are no longer here) that, when the database is downloaded and opened on my local computer, shows two yellow notification under the ribbon but above the switchboard.
The first yellow notification bar says "Security Warning Some active content has been disabled. Click for more details. and a button that says Enable Content."
The second yellow notification bar says "Save Changes. Save your changes to the server. and a button that says Save to SharePoint Site."

How do I get that second yellow notification to work with my new database?